# How can I maximally compress .gz files in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, compression, gzip

When selecting *Compress...* from the right click context menu in Nautilus I am able to quickly compress files to .gz format.

However by default Nautilus does not use maximum compression. Can I make Nautilus to use maximum compression like `gzip -9`?

Using gconftool or gconf-editor to set the compression_level for File Roller to `maximum` seems right but infortunately has not the desired effect and will not lead to maximum compressed files. As this is the expected way of how to set compression levels a [bug report has been filed](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644162) upstream.

Any ideas for a workaround are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply run:

```
gconftool --type String --set /apps/file-roller/general/compression_level maximum
```

Other options for this setting: `very_fast` `fast` `normal`

Edit: This doesn't appear to be well implemented. I have compressed a text file (highly compressible) using a number of different formats using `normal` and `maximum` settings:

```
52167 client.h  # uncompressed

15980 client.h.normal.7z
15979 client.h.max.7z

15861 client.h.normal.bz2
15861 client.h.max.bz2

17034 client.h.normal.gz
17034 client.h.max.gz

15892 client.h.normal.lzma
15892 client.h.max.lzma

16641 client.h.normal.zip
16486 client.h.max.zip
```

`zip` was the only format that showed any real difference (still tiny on the scale of things).

Comment: I am seriously impressed!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, even after log out/log in, file-roller creates `.gz` files of the same size whatever the compression level in gconf settings ;( In strace the command is always the same: `execve("/bin/gzip", ["gzip", "--", "a.txt"]`...

Comment: This seems to be the proper way of doing but it does not work for me either.

Comment: @arrange and @Takkat I've done some testing and have added it to the post. Seems only `zip` has this implemented.

Comment: Well, the difference between `normal` and `maximum` is small, IMO you should have tested the difference between `very_fast` and `maximum`. On my system file-roller honours the set preferences, the only case where it fails to do so is for `gzip` (and `bz2`) files, I don't know why.

Comment: @arrange it's not so much the small amount of compression that matters. For a DEB package you need .gz files with explicit maximum compression or it will fail to install from the Software Center in 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

As there is an obvious bug with File Roller not using gconf settings we need to define a [Nautilus Script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nautilus_Scripts) to perform maximum compression from right click context menu:

```
#! /bin/sh

gzip -9 $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
```

Save this file as executable with any name like `Gz-max` to `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`.